# How to get the base constructor calling parameters with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How to get the hard-coded parameter that the sub-class constructor is used to call the base-class constructor?

```
public class BaseMessage
{
    public BaseMessage(string format, params string[] parameteres)
    {
    }
}

public class HelloMessage : BaseMessage
{
    public HelloMessage(string name) : base("Hello {0}", name)
    {
    }
}

public class IntroductionMessage : BaseMessage
{
    public IntroductionMessage(string name, string myName) : base("Hello {0}, I am {1}", name, myName)
    {
    }
}
```

I would like to get all the hard-coded formatting string for the sub-classes of BaseMessage, i.e. "Hello {0}" and "Hello {0}, I am {1}"

Comment: Read the format-string within your base-constructor. I don´t understand what the problem is, nor why you think you need reflection, nor why this question was upvoted three times, although there are not much own affords.

Comment: To do this *via reflection* is probably going to require you to inspect the IL in a method body; is that a viable option for you? This isn't part of the readily available metadata. Are you sure you can't just look at what value arrives in the base class?

Comment: In addition to what I wrote earlier, why not simply use `Console.WriteLine(format)` within `BaseMessage`? I don´t get, what you´re *actually* trying to solve. Might be an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Thanks for your comment.. The real situation is: I would like to list these bulit-in messages to UI for customizing the format-string. Sometime the sub-class is not that easy to construct in the config controller (e.g. required a complex object and passing some of its fields to the base constructor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*At the reflection level*, the only place this exists is in the method body of the constructor, which gets compiled as (`HelloMessage`):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void
    .ctor(string name) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldstr "Hello {0}"
    L_0006: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0007: newarr string
    L_000c: dup 
    L_000d: ldc.i4.0 
    L_000e: ldarg.1 
    L_000f: stelem.ref 
    L_0010: call instance void BaseMessage::.ctor(string, string[])
    L_0015: ret 
}
```

or (`IntroductionMessage`):

```
.method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void
    .ctor(string name, string myName) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldstr "Hello {0}, I am {1}"
    L_0006: ldc.i4.2 
    L_0007: newarr string
    L_000c: dup 
    L_000d: ldc.i4.0 
    L_000e: ldarg.1 
    L_000f: stelem.ref 
    L_0010: dup 
    L_0011: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0012: ldarg.2 
    L_0013: stelem.ref 
    L_0014: call instance void BaseMessage::.ctor(string, string[])
    L_0019: ret 
}
```

So; *via reflection* you would have to get the method body (`MethodInfo.GetMethodBody().GetILAsByteArray()`) and *manually deconstruct it* (noting that you'll have **compiled IL** to deal with, not the text version I've shown). This is *possible*, but is massively over-complicated for what you probably want. There *are* runtime IL disassembly tools, but... again: massively overkill here.

I would recommend either:

- just look at what values arrive in `format` in the `BaseMessage` at runtime
- use a *compile-time* tool such as an analyzer - or parse the source with Roslyn - and get the data at build
- something involving attributes or properties; it is pretty easy to get values from attributes or properties

Comment: OP "I have a problem!" - Marc "Here is the nuke!" ;)

Comment: @RandRandom hopefully if you show a scary enough nuke, they'll find a peaceful solution instead :) Hmmm.... maybe I shouldn't go into politics.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your answer. I think I will give up this approach and turn those parameters into static fields instead..